# 必殺技 scope of usage

Tags: meaning

必殺技 translates as "killer technique", but does this only apply to physical fighting or does it have a broader usage? For example, can I have a 必殺技 for making perfectly crispy roast potatoes? Would it be a natural usage?

Comment: 食戟のソーマでありそう（観たことないですが）

Comment: @Angelos Great anime. I don't want to end up sounding like Souma though. I'll have to watch again now and see if he uses that word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose 必殺技 can be used in a broader sense, but still in some sort of fighting/beating context.

For example, consider someone is a expert of specific technology (e.g. a particular technique of machine learning) and s/he uses it to solve a problem. Then one could say 彼(女)は必殺技で問題を解決した.

I guess making perfectly crispy roast potatoes itself is unlikely to be called a 必殺技. Rather, if it involves some techniques (right amount of oil, using something unusual etc.), then those could be called a 必殺技 (for beating the task of making roast potatoes).